# Why is Python Turtle listen() not working?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am very, and by that I mean very new to Python (i know literally nothing). I'm attemtping to create a little game using the turtle module, and following a tutorial I don't see the listen() function working

here's my code
I'm trying to create a controllable character

```
from turtle import *

#background
Screen().bgcolor("orange")

#player

pl = Turtle()
pl.color('dodgerblue')
pl.shape('turtle')
pl.penup()

def turnleft():
    player.left(30)

turtle.listen()
onkeypress(turnleft, "Left")

speed = 1
while True:
    pl.forward(speed)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `from turtle import *` it imports everything into the built-in namespace, i.e., you can then just do:

```
listen()
```

rather than

```
turtle.listen()
```

If you had just done

```
import turtle
```

then everything in the `turtle` package would then be accessed through the `turtle` namespace, i.e.,

```py
turtle.listen()
```

Comment: [16:0] name 'listen' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of mistakes here, totally normal because you are so new, that's the way to get better.

I will ""arrange"" a bit your code.

```
import turtle

#background
turtle.Screen().bgcolor("orange")

#player
pl = turtle.Turtle()
pl.color('dodgerblue')
pl.shape('turtle')
pl.penup()

def turnleft():
    pl.left(30)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(turnleft, "Left")

speed = 1
while True:
    pl.forward(speed)
```

First of all i recommend you to check in google what is "OOP" and check how it works on Python.

When you use "functions" from a module (in this case turtle) , you need to call first the module and after the function for example:

```
turtle.onkeypress(turnleft, "Left")
# Instead
onkeypress(turnleft,"Left")
```

Another thing it's in your function "**turnleft**" you call the variable "**player**", but "**player**" doesnt exist, you want to call "**pl**".

Good luck with your small new projects, keep trying.

Comment: i replaced the code with what you wrote, but it still gives me an error
I have a screenshot link https://pic8.co/sh/xGijR2.png

Comment: @Birbz I dont gonna lie, i'm a bit confuse right now... witch versión of python are you using or in wich thing are you coding?.  Because with the info i have i cant know why is making that error.